# White line in outlook

Tags: html, outlook

I'm trying to design up some new html email signatures for our charity that will be used in Outlook - however for some reason there is a 1px white line appearing between two of the bottom images that make up the signature when it's added to Outlook, it's fine when you just open it on eg. Safari / Chrome. Can anyone help?

Thanks

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
 td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
 img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" width="649" height="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">
   <div style="height:200px">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hfgS2Y0/Idea-1-01.jpg" width="492" height="200" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <a href="http://www.ygam.org"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/4V8fjdf/Idea-1-02.jpg" alt="Idea-1-02" width="42" height="44" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/young-gamblers-education-trust/about/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xsv5cFM/Idea-1-03.jpg" width="36" height="44" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/YGAMuk/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/tqN4kc1/Idea-1-04.jpg" width="34" height="44" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/YGAMuk"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/wyr3QB8/Idea-1-05.jpg" width="45" height="44" alt=""></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4">
   <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3TsGJC2/Idea-1-06.jpg" width="157" height="56" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4">
   <a href="http://www.ygam.org"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/BT6MZ7N/Idea-1-07.jpg" width="157" height="100" alt=""></a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

#### The Problem

Outlook's dreaded white lines often appear horizontally below a block of text, image, or table when viewing HTML email messages.  Vertical white lines are also possible, at the edges of text or block elements.  Only Windows versions of Outlook are affected.

```
<table style="background-color: #cccccc"><tr><td>This is<br>some text.</td>
<td><table><tr><td>More text<td></tr><tr><td>over here.</td></tr></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>More text down here.</td></tr></table>
```

[image: Horizontal white lines in Outlook: 150% display scaling and 115% zoom][image: Vertical white lines in Outlook: 150% display scaling and 117% zoom]

It seems to be a bug in how Outlook calculates the dimensions of features when scaling them to screen pixels. I surmise that Outlook is calculating a width or height value that has a fractional component, which gets rounded incorrectly someplace in Outlook's processing.  It creates a 1-pixel gap in the screen rendering that allows the background color to show through.

The appearance of white lines is quite unpredictable.  It depends on the HTML, but also on how text and other elements wrap on the user's screen, and on the user's Outlook and Windows settings. If you want to torture your HTML, try changing Outlook's zoom setting to values in the 101% to 124% range, and you'll quickly discover some of the places where a white line could appear.

#### The Solution

An HTML designer can't always avoid white lines in Outlook, because its scaling depends on the user's settings.  But you can avoid white lines for the majority of users by following a couple of rules:

1. For all text, set line-height values that are multiples of 4px.  White space must be included. To ensure that all text is included and Outlook uses the exact px value you declare, I suggest creating every table like this:
   `<table style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px">`
   and then set larger line-height multiples of 4px on block elements like `tr` or `td` wherever you need larger fonts, e.g.,
   `<td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; font-size: 20px">`
   Generally you'll want a line-height around 1.25 times the font-size.
2. Set all other width and height values to multiples of 4px.  That includes borders, padding, margins, and the widths and heights of images.  There are a few possible exceptions:

   - Tables that are just containers for other tables and have no text or images of their own need not be restricted to multiples of 4px.
   - Borders and padding on the same side of an element need not be multiples of 4px if they add to a multiple of 4px.  For example,
     `<a style="border-top:1px solid black; padding-top:3px">`
     `<table style="border-top:1px solid black; padding-top:2px">`
     (Yes, 1+2=4 thanks to another Outlook bug that adds a table's border thickness to the padding on that side.)

These rules prevent white lines when Outlook's zoom is set to 100% and Windows' display scaling is set to one of the built-in values, which are all multiples of 25%.

#### How It Works

Outlooks scales text, borders, margins, padding, and images to screen pixels directly by its zoom setting and Windows' display scaling factor.  Setting the feature dimensions to multiples of 4px ensures that the calculated screen dimensions are whole numbers of pixels when Outlook's zoom is 100% and Windows' display scaling factor is a multiple of 25%. Avoiding fractional screen pixel dimensions avoids the Outlook bug that would round them incorrectly. And of course, `0px` is a magical value that always scales to a whole number, for any zoom setting or display scaling factor.

I'm sure there are more exceptions and subtlety left to discover, and I can't promise this will fix every white line.  But this solution has worked for my HTML across a range of Outlook versions and Windows display settings.  I tested Outlook for Microsoft 365 Version 2208, Outlook 2021, Outlook 2019, Outlook 2016, Windows 10 Mail, and Windows 11 Mail.  Try it for yourself and let us know if it works.

#### Line Heights in Outlook

Outlook automatically calculates the height required for each line based on the characters in the line and on the font, style, and font-size of each character.  For normal text, the calculated line height will usually be around 1.25 times the font-size (less for large fonts), but it can be larger if there are unusually tall characters (special characters like U+FF5C, and some non-Latin scripts).  And if the text has a border, the line height can be larger to accommodate the thickness of the border and padding.  This calculated line height is almost never a whole number of pixels, and it can vary from line to line.

When you don't declare a line-height, Outlook uses the line height it calculated.

When you declare a line-height as a percentage, Outlook scales the line height it calculated by the percentage.

Under Outlook's default mso-line-height-rule of `at-least`, when you declare a line-height in px, Outlook compares the value it calculated to the value you declared.  The value you declared is only used if it is at least as large as what Outlook calculated.  In other words, by default, a line-height px declaration can only make a line taller.

When you declare `mso-line-height-rule: exactly` before a line-height declaration in px, Outlook uses the exact px value you declared.  Note however that if the line-height you declared is shorter than the height Outlook calculated, the line can be pushed down so it is not vertically centered, or even cut off at the top if the line-height is much smaller than the font-size.

Inheritance of mso-line-height-rule is unreliable, so I suggest declaring it directly before every line-height.  Line-height declarations only work when declared on block elements.

`mso-line-height-rule: exactly` is the fastest and easiest way to avoid Outlook's white line bug, when used with line-height values that are multiples of 4px.  But I recommend this option only when the text is under your control, as there's some risk of misformatting.

The default mso-line-height-rule of "at-least" is foolproof for general formatting, but is a trickier option when you're trying to prevent Outlook's white line bug.  To prevent white lines using this option, you'll need to make sure you declare a line-height px value that is a multiple of 4px, and is also larger than the line height Outlook calculated.  Declaring a line-height larger than 1.25 times the font-size is sufficient on most normal text, but again, it depends on what exactly is in the line.  To be certain, you'll need to test Outlook with specific text and no line-height declaration, and measure the pixel height of the rendered line on your screen.

Comment: This is a great tip and thanks for sharing @balazer, I've added it to the fixes shared here: Fixing white lines in Outlook - https://www.actionrocket.co/email-design-review/white-lines-in-outlook

Comment: Oh, don't feed my resentments against some unfortunately common products ... ;-)

Comment: Thanks, changing font size from 14px to 12px fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

### **Try using an explicit space**

In some particular versions of Outlook (2016 and 2019 come to mind), whenever you have a strange 1px border appear on an element, try adding a space, by forcing it with `&nbsp;`, before the relevant parent closing `</td>`. Obviously this assumes you're not already setting a border elsewhere (through table props or css).

For example, this fix worked for me...

**FAILS**: a strange 1px line may appear at the bottom of the element:

```
... my link</a></td>
```

**WORKS**: no strange line appears:

```
... my link</a>&nbsp;</td>
```

It's related to how some versions of Outlook process white space in your code. In the original code above (example A), obviously there's no white space space directly between `</a>` and `</td>`, so I suspect the issue goes beyond the enclosing `td`, and the structure and/or white space of your surrounding code matters. If this is the case, then using `&nbsp;` (example B) is just a quick fix in lieu of re-structuring your code. Alternatively, optimize (compress) your code through a pre-processor and see what happens.

On a side note, using a major testing platform, all other email clients (+40 being tested) seemed to have no issue with the extra `&nbsp;` in place.

Answer (score 0):

So, after working for days and testing I figured out the solution for lines appearing in outlook.you just have to give background color like this to the table where you've used background-color.

```html
<table style="background: #000000;backgroud-color: #000000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" padding="0" bgColor="#000000">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ffffff;">
        Your code
      </td>
    <tr/>
  </tbody>
</table>
```